# Como fazer um select se repetir inteiro 1 vez pra cada mês em um range de datas de forma dinamica?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Supondo que eu tenho vendas que aconteceram no mês de Maio. Eu poderia fazer o seguinte select: `SELECT * FROM Vendas WHERE MONTH(Data_Venda) = 5`

Supondo que o mês de Junho aconteceu e agora eu tenho vendas em Junho, poderia fazer o seguinte select: `SELECT * FROM Vendas WHERE MONTH(Data_Venda) = 6`

Supondo que eu queria ver as vendas de Maio e Junho, eu poderia fazer o seguinte select: `SELECT * FROM Vendas WHERE MONTH(Data_Venda) IN(5, 6)`

Porém meu caso é mais complexo do que esse e eu não posso pegar as "vendas" desses 2 meses da forma que mencionei anteriormente, eu poderia fazer da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT * FROM Vendas WHERE MONTH(Data_Venda) = 5 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM Vendas WHERE MONTH(Data_Venda) = 6
```

Como mencionei anteriormente, a forma mais logica e sensata seria o `> 5` ou `IN(5,6)`, mas os dados que eu preciso buscar não são vendas e não estão registrados de uma forma que eu possa fazer da forma mais normal. A questão das vendas foi apenas um exemplo para facilitar o entendimento.

A minha duvida é como eu fazer o seguinte select de forma dinamica, ou seja, vou passar uma data inicial (mês e ano) e uma final (mês e ano) e o script fosse "acrescentado" `UNION SELECT * FROM Vendas WHERE MONTH = @Mes` de forma dinamica?

```
 SELECT * FROM Vendas WHERE MONTH(Data_Venda) = 5 
 UNION 
 SELECT * FROM Vendas WHERE MONTH(Data_Venda) = 6
```

O meu script é pequeno até, tem por volta de 80 linhas e possui`SELECT INTO`, `DELETE` em tabela #temporaria, `UPDATE` em tabela #temporaria e `SELECT` normal no final.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/389b4c32-96b7-413b-9a25-858ad5835f20/pesquisa-sql-por-ms-e-ano?forum=520

Comment: Cara, acho que vc quer um query builder. Se eu entendi o exemplo, eu não faria com UNION, utilizaria o BETWEEN no WHERE. Deste modo o builder faria combinações de BETWEENs.

Answer (score 0):

Do que eu entendi, voce esta querendo executar a seguinte query

```
SELECT * 
FROM vendas 
WHERE 
YEAR(Data_Venda) >= [ano do periodo inicial] AND 
MONTH(Data_Venda) >= [mes do periodo inicial] AND
YEAR(Data_Venda) <= [ano do periodo final] AND 
MONTH(Data_Venda) <= [mes do periodo final]
```

espero resposta :)